# simple css element positioning

Tags: css, css-float

My page can be found [here](http://www.vypadavanie.net/sampon-proti-vypadavaniu-vlasov-revita).

Under product picture there is a black video box. I want it to float left, so the small product pictures are inline with video box. Not able to do that. I went through CSS to see if there is some weird positioning involved but I couldn't find nothing.

If I move the videobox ABOVE the Facebookbutton and make it float, everything works as expected - Facebook button moves up.

Comment: That's a lot to dig through... the relevant bits are nested twelve deep.  Can you post a jsFiddle demo?  Also, I don't see `float` applied to the video button or any of its nested `div`'s so I'm not sure how you expect it to float left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set both item containers (divs) to "display:inline-block", and set a width for the video div "width:70px" for example. Take a look at the screenshot for more info: [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA9Vl.png)

Margins and paddings would help you to correctly center vertically your video box in the row, but your major problem is solved with those CSS rules

Hope it helps!! :-)

[image: check it here]

Comment: what works for me was to float left the vido-colorbox and to set the second div inline-block as you suggested. Can you tell why it was not working only using float:left to the first div? I did it a few times on my oage and it worked. Is it because that second div contains tables or something?  thank you

Comment: display:block makes your div behave like a <br/>, i mean, the next content will be rendered just below it.That is why you should use display:inline-block. (inline to remove the fake <br> and block to behave like a div and not like an span).  Setting the width of the video box also helps because if you dont, then it will expand to 100%, so there is no space left for the second row. Take care!

Answer (score 1):

Add `float: left;` to the `view-content` class.

```
.view-content {
  float: left;
}
```